# Относительный путь к файлу C#

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, процесс, path, testng

Есть простая консольная программка:

```
int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(args[0]);
int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
return (int)Math.Pow(number1, number2);
```

Нужно написать модульные тесты, используя Process. Когда задаю FileName и использую абсолютный путь, то всё работает корректно.

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\R3-D3\source\repos\testing\Example\bin\Debug\Example.exe";
```

Но, нужно поменять абсолютный путь на относительный. Но ни "Example\bin\Debug\Example.exe", ни "..\Example\bin\Debug\Example.exe" не работают.

Как задать относительный путь?

Comment: А в Environment.CurrentDirectory что? Относительный путь относительно текущей директории строится.

Comment: Я посмотрел, в Environment.CurrentDirectory у меня C:\Users\R3-D3. Соответственно, написал `StartInfo.FileName = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\source\repos\testing\Example\bin\Debug\Example.exe";`
Но ничего не меняется, даже если задавать путь по-другому

Comment: Выведите в консоль то что получается при спаривании путей и то что у вас с абсолтной строке и сравните. И вообще, вам бы познакомиться с `Path.Combine`. Отлаживайте код, без отладки у вас не получится ничего нормального разработать.